# Proguard error : Unknown option '-optimizationpasses'

Tags: android, proguard

My Proguard builds used to work in earlier Android SDKs (pre-10), but not any more, and its a very basic error - see below:

C:\development\android-sdk-windows\tools\ant\main_rules.xml:453: Unknown option
'-optimizationpasses' in line 1 of file 'C:\Users\Richard\Desktop\CodeWordTEST\p
roguard.cfg'

i.e. proguard fails on the first line.
Interestingly, if I remove the  '-optimizationpasses' command it manages to go a little further through the proguard options, but then fails on '-dontpreverify'

Something seems to have changed, so I went back to basics.

I built a project from the command line, to get the default build.xml and proguard.cfg files.

Still the same error.

Environment:

- Windows 7
- ADT Version: 11.0.0.v201105251008-128486
- Ant 1.8.1
- no other Proguard in the env path

proguard.cfg contents (=default as auto-generated by android cmd line):

-optimizationpasses 5

-dontusemixedcaseclassnames

-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses

-dontpreverify

-verbose

-optimizations !code/simplification/arithmetic,!field/*,!class/merging/*

etc...

Any ideas what might be causing the problem?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: OK, simple but non-obvious fix for anyone else who finds this problem.

Contrary to the Android docs (http://developer.android.com/sdk/tools-notes.html), Ant 1.8 onwards isn't good enough.

Use Ant 1.8.2.

Magic occurs.

(If anyone knows the reason it works, feel free to post. It would be nice to understand.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Contrary to the Android docs (developer.android.com/sdk/tools-notes.html), Ant 1.8 onwards isn't good enough:

**Use Ant 1.8.2.**

If anyone knows the reason why 1.8.2 is required, we'd love to know.
Cheers...

Answer (score 1):

The errors suggest that you were somehow using a very old version of ProGuard (optimization was introduced in 3.0 in 2004, preverification in 4.0 in 2007).

Comment: Hello Eric, thanks for you answer. This was on a Win7 dev PC with no Proguard in the path, so it was using the Proguard within the Android SDK. Moving from Ant 1.8.1 to Ant 1.8.2 did the trick, but I don't understand why. Been using Proguard 4.4 previously on older Android SDKs so I get the feeling it was an SDK 11 <--> Ant clash. No proof though...